# MongoDB Search nested Objects without knowing Key

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

I have a list of objects that are given somewhat arbitrary Object keys as a result of using the async Java driver + BSON.

[image]

My issue is given the fact that `jobStatuses` are an arbitrary list of Dictionary items where I don't know the key, I have no idea how to access its sub-values. In the end, I'm trying to build a query that returns if ANY of `jobStatus.*._id` are true given a list of potential Object ID's.

So I'd be giving a list of ID's and want to return true if ANY of the items in `jobStatuses` have any of the given ID's. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            jobStatutses: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $objectToArray: "$jobStatutses" }, 0] }
        }
    }, {
        $match: { 'jobStatutses.v._id': { $in: [ObjectId("5d6d8c3a5a0d22d3c84dd6dc"), ObjectId("5d6d8c3a5a0d22d3c84dd6ed")] } }
    }
])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06319c400289966eea6a07"),
    "jobStatutses" : {
        "5d6d8c3a5a0d22d3c84dd6dc" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d8c3a5a0d22d3c84dd6dc"),
            "accepted" : "123",
            "completed" : 0
        }
    },
    "something" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0631ad400289966eea6dd1"),
    "jobStatutses" : {
        "5d6d8c3a5a0d22d3c84dd6ed" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d8c3a5a0d22d3c84dd6ed"),
            "accepted" : "456",
            "completed" : 0
        }
    },
    "something" : 2
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0631cd400289966eea7542"),
    "jobStatutses" : {
        "5e06319c400289966eea6a07" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e06319c400289966eea6a07"),
            "accepted" : "789",
            "completed" : 0
        }
    },
    "something" : 3
}
```

**Output :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "jobStatutses" : {
        "k" : "5d6d8c3a5a0d22d3c84dd6dc",
        "v" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d8c3a5a0d22d3c84dd6dc"),
            "accepted" : "123",
            "completed" : 0
        }
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "jobStatutses" : {
        "k" : "5d6d8c3a5a0d22d3c84dd6ed",
        "v" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d8c3a5a0d22d3c84dd6ed"),
            "accepted" : "456",
            "completed" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

All you need is to check if at least one doc gets returned from DB for a given list or not, So we don't need to worry about document structure then just do `result.length` in your code to say at least one doc got matched for the input list.

Comment: Sweet! This seems to work to do the matching properly. How do I then return the whole document as the result, rather than just the data of `jobStatuses`?

Comment: @Cryptite : Do you need whole document as is from DB ? That case this operation might become a bit bulky, It's ok depends on your collections data & indexes - give it a try - If it's needed then in `$project` stage remove `_id` & also replace `$project` with `$addFields` & replace `jobStatutses` with `jobStatutsesArr` & atlast add third stage `$project` to remove `jobStatutsesArr`. Result would seem pretty much same like your original docs !!