# can't get data for unknown key in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to get a subarray from a document using mongodb queries but I don't know the key for it. My data looks something like this:

`{ 'log file name I dont know': [Array] }`

'log file name I dont know' is the unique key at that level. Is there something like "get value for the first key" in mongodb aggregation pipeline?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503339/mongodb-search-nested-objects-without-knowing-key) might help

Comment: The problem is, keys have no order so "the first key" is not defined.

Comment: I don't understand how you would want to "get" something if you don't know the key for it -- or do you mean to just get *all* the keys and subarrays for each?

Answer (score 0):

1 Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    new: {
      $first: "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "map": {
      "$objectToArray": "$new"
    }
  }
},
{
  $unwind: "$map"
},
{
  $match: {
    "map.k": {
      "$ne": "_id"
   },
      "map.v": 4
  }
 }
])
```

Explained:

1. Add the root document to new key named "new"
2. Convert the object named "new" to array named "map"
3. $unwind the array
4. Remove the array elements with k:"_id" , so in the final result to have only:
   map.k  -> the unknown keys
   map.v -> the array values for the unknown keys

Finally you can add in the $match stage the searched element , in the example:"map.v":4

[playground1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F7RmEadenv6)

---

2 Here is the option when you want to preserve the strange structure with the unknown key after the match stage:

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      new: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
       }
     }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "map": {
        "$objectToArray": "$new"
       }
     }
  },
  {
    $match: {
     "map.v": 1
  }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "map": {
       "$arrayToObject": "$map"
   }
  }
  },
  {
     $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$map"
     }
  }
  ])
```

Explained:

1. Add the root document to new key named "new"
2. Convert the object named "new" to array named "map"
3. Match the necessary documents(in the example this is array element 1 ( "map.v":1 )
4. Convert back the array to object.
5. Replace the root tocument with the "map docunent" so it looks as original collection

[playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DrdBJTwijyX)

Few words: File name value is not recommended to be a key , best practice is the filename to be key/value so if you want to search on filename value to be possible to create index on that filename key field  , so your json structure to looke something like:

```
  { "filename":"The unknown file name"  , "theArray":[1,2,3] }
```